# Export captured powershell data to csv file

Tags: powershell

I have been trying to get the scripts below to export to a csv file. I am pretty new to Powershell. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
# get-content H:\src\win\hostlist.txt | % { 
# @("dsp021","dsp075") | % { 
@("dsp075") | % { 
write "Name, Manufacturer, Model"
gwmi win32_computersystem -ComputerName $_  | select  -Property Manufacturer, Model, Name
gwmi win32_computersystemproduct  -ComputerName $_ | select uuid 
write "mac addresses:"
gwmi win32_networkadapter -ComputerName $_  | ? { $_.MACAddress -match ":" } | select MACAddress
write "Solarflare network IDs"
gwmi win32_pnpentity -ComputerName $_ | ? { $_.Manufacturer -match "Solar"} | Select Name,DeviceID
write "LSI Disk controller IDs"
gwmi win32_pnpentity -ComputerName $_| ? { $_.Manufacturer -match "LSI"} | Select Name,DeviceID 
} |Format-list
```

Thank you!

Comment: there are a few syntax errors in the script you posted, what is happening when you run it?

Comment: Yeah, the code as posted would not even run. At the very least, there is an unclosed quote at the end.

Comment: If I dont even try to export as a csv and just do Format-table.... is returns the data I am looking for.

Comment: Please fix the syntax errors in your code. Edit the question and copy and paste if that is the easiest for you, but however you want to do it you will need to put up the code that you are actually running if you want to get help.

Comment: I updated the code to what actually works. This returns the data I need, but now need to get it to a csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your code so it can be exportable into a CSV file.
I am not sure if this is the format you wanted but it should give you an idea.

```
@("computername") | % { 
     gwmi win32_computersystem -ComputerName $_  | select  -Property Manufacturer, Model, Name | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
     gwmi win32_computersystemproduct  -ComputerName $_ | select uuid | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
     #write "mac addresses:" 
     gwmi win32_networkadapter -ComputerName $_  | ? { $_.MACAddress -match ":" } | select @{Name="Mac Addresses";Expression={$_."MACAddress"}}  |  ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
     #write "Solarflare network IDs"
     gwmi win32_pnpentity -ComputerName $_ | ? { $_.Manufacturer -match "Solar"} | Select @{Name="Solarflare network Names";Expression={$_."Name"}} ,@{Name="Device IDs";Expression={$_."DeviceID"}} | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
     #write "LSI Disk controller IDs"
     gwmi win32_pnpentity -ComputerName $_| ? { $_.Manufacturer -match "LSI"} | Select @{Name="LSI Disk controller Names";Expression={$_."Name"}} ,@{Name="Device IDs";Expression={$_."DeviceID"}}  |ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
} | out-file C:\works.csv
```

The script convert all commands out-put into CSV before exporting everything into a file.

Comment: Fantastic... I just had to make a few minor tweaks and it ran great. Thank you very much!!!!